# pyinstaller 3.2 with django 1.10.1

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

System: windows 7 64 bit, python 3.5, anaconda 3 (64 bit) , django 1.10.1

I'm trying to compile my django project in 2 ways:

First:

```
[Anaconda3] c:\compilation\Gui>pyinstaller --name=gui --exclude-module=PyQt4 --exclude-module=matplotlib --clean --win-private-assemblies manage.py
```

Second according to [this soloution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479049/pyinstaller-django-with-custom-admin-commands):

```
[Anaconda3] c:\compilation\Gui>pyinstaller --name=gui --exclude-module=PyQt4 --exclude-module=matplotlib --clean --win-private-assemblies --runtime-hook=pyi_rth_django.py manage.py
```

When I try to run the output:

```
c:\compilation\Gui\dist\gui>gui.exe runserver
```

I get (for the 2 versions I get the same output):

```
c:\compilation\Gui\dist\gui>gui.exe runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x00000000044E9D90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
File "site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
File "site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
File "site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
File "site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
File "site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.admin.apps'
```

Please advice.

Comment: Add `runserver` to the end of your `pyinstaller` command, so that it could detect additional dependency?

Comment: Could you kindly demonstrate? [my try failed with errors , the --runtime-hook=pyi_rth_django.py seems to cover the runserver cmd].

Comment: `pyinstaller --name=gui --exclude-module=PyQt4 --exclude-module=matplotlib --clean --win-private-assemblies manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: This is what I tried I get
    ValueError: script 'c:\compilation\Gui\runserver' not found

Answer (score 1):

What is your files layout? According to these `pyinstaller` docs https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django there could be two solutions.

1. run your command from parent directory, i.e. instead of

   ```
   c:\compilation\Gui>pyinstaller --name=gui manage.py
   ```

   do

   ```
   c:\compilation>pyinstaller --name=gui Gui\manage.py
   ```
2. try to add `import django.contrib.admin.apps` to your `manage.py` and make sure it exists
3. [report bug](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django#what-if-it-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

To fix the "ImportError: No module named django.contrib.admin.apps" problem you have to create a directory, let's call it "your_project/other_hooks". 
Inside that directory create a file called  hook-django.contrib.py with this content:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('django.contrib')
```

Now call pyinstaller in this way:

```
pyinstaller --name=yourProject --additional-hooks-dir=your_project\other_hooks  your_project\manage.py
```

While you can use any name for the directory, the file name is mandatory, it has to be "hook-django.contrib.py".

Hope this helps.

References:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2332
https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/hooks.html#how-a-hook-is-loaded

Comment: It's worked for `django.contrib.admin.apps` but now I run into `No module named 'django.contrib.staticfiles.apps'`. How to fix this one? I thought since it's also a `django.contrib` it would be fixed with the hook described above??