# How to create an executable portable version of a django project

Tags: python, django, webserver

I wish to create a peer to peer network (communications done via HTTP) of nodes running a django project of mine.
Is there anyway I can package my django project with a suitable web server and SQLite such that I can distribute an executable version of it to users which they can then run with one click?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325296/pyinstaller-3-2-with-django-1-10-1)?