# Pyinstaller with Django: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.admin.apps'

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

I'm getting an error when trying to run my packaged python application in cmd line:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.admin.apps'
```

I tried the answer from [pyinstaller 3.2 with django 1.10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325296/pyinstaller-3-2-with-django-1-10-1), but I still get the same error. The only difference is a `ModuleNotFoundError` rather than an `ImportError`. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *PyInstaller/hooks/* location you should add the hook file and import hidden modules.

More: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2332

Comment: Do I need to create the path /Pyinstaller/hooks/ in the app folder? Or will there be a folder for that somewhere already?

Comment: I am facing same issue, can you help me?